# Prisma Error while creating - Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `foreign key`

Tags: javascript, prisma, sveltekit

I play around with Prisma with following Models:

```
model Articles {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  article_desc String
  Prices       Prices[]
}

model Prices {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  price       Float
  article_id  Int
  Articles    Articles     @relation(fields: [article_id], references: [id])
  Articlelist Articlelist? @relation(fields: [article_id], references: [articleID])
}

model Articlelist {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  articleID    Int      @unique
  article_desc String
  Prices       Prices[]
}
```

When I try to create an new entry with:

```
await prisma.articles.create({
            data: {
                article_desc,
                Prices: {
                    create: {
                        price
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I got the following error:

```
Invalid `prisma.articles.create()` invocation:
Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `foreign key`
```

Cane someone help me out with this?

Comment: You are not passing `article_id` while creating a price which is a required field, hence you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `article_id` to create price:

```
await prisma.articles.create({
            data: {
                article_desc,
                Prices: {
                    create: {
                        price,
                        article_id
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

Price entity requires article foreign key to be created